# Lower Bound on Dimension of Orthogonal Complements

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I came across this result, and was trying to understand why it is true:
Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $U \subset V$, and has a bilinear form $b: V \times V \xrightarrow{} k$, then we define the orthogonal complement $U^\perp$ as:

$$
U^\perp = \{v \in V | b(v, w) = 0 \forall w \in U\}
$$

As such, we have $dim(U) \leq dim(U^\perp)$.

Is there any reason as to how to prove this result? The only result to do with dimensions of $U^\perp$ that I know of is that $dim(U) + dim(U^{\perp}) = dim(V)$, but it doesn't seem to help in any way.

Comment: I don't think it's true. Let $U$ be the subspace $(x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with the usual dot product as our bilinear form. Then $U^\perp$ is the subspace given by $(0,0,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and it has dimension strictly less than $U$.